# msysgit opens git.exe at every command

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I installed msysgit on Windows 8.1, it works pretty well, I can do everything I want. The only problem is, everytime I type a command or even just press enter in the msysgit terminal, it opens a new git.exe window which closes shortly after.

This windows prompts some stuff which are not always the same, such as :

```
.git
false
false
true
f84697e
```

For instance.

It's pretty annoying and I can't seem to find why it does that.

What does this happens and how can I stop it ?

EDIT:

Okay I looked around a bit, and it seems that every command I type is executed in this new window (which executes git.exe in the msysgit folder)

Comment: Are you using it in a Git for Windows bash shell? (instead of a regular cmd shell). In that case, check your `.profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes I am, I looked up my .bashrc, apart from my aliases there's nothing in there. As for the .profile I don't seem to have one.

Comment: Ok. I generally use Git for windows in a cmd shell, not the bash shell. I use `https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat`